# Issues getting Node.js running with MongoDB on Windows Azure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure

I have been struggling to do the tutorial, https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/web-app-with-mongodb/, which basically makes a simple node.js application that has access to a Mongo DB. I keep running into the following issue when launching the program locally with the command Start-AzureEmulator:

"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:27017"

I tried various ports and configurations with no success. Oddly enough, when I run mongodb.exe, the database launches without hiccup (this is just through the command line not within the Azure Emulator). I have also tried reinstalling all of the tools multiple times. It seems I am at a loss of what to do next.

Have any of you experienced this problem or have been able to complete this tutorial?

As a side note, do any of you know any cloud providers that allow the use of sockets with node.js? This is one of the main reasons I am trying to use Azure.

Comment: Do you have a space in your home directory? e.g. C:\Users\first last\

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've followed the instructions step by step and haven't modified anything yet?

I note from the screenshot below, that the sample tries to open Mongo at 127.***255***.0.1:27017, not 127.0.0.1:27017:

[image: Mongo & Node Service URL's]

I suggest checking your Azure services' URL's in case you're looking for Mongo on the wrong address.